# How to recieve a message from a Webservice with KSOAP2 and Android

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

i tried to do a simple ksoap2 tutorial. This is the [link](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.de/2010/11/basic-ksoap-android-tutorial.html)

My Problem is, I only get a response, if I use SoapPrimitive and Ksoap...2.6.4.jar with Ksoap...2.4.jar and or "SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();"  I've got an exception.

How i have to use the SoapObject?

This is my Code:

```
public class WS_Auth_ComplexObjectsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    String NAMESPACE = "http://WS.androidroleplay.fk4.de.hs_bremen.de";
    String METHOD_NAME = "GetSumOfTwoInts";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://WS.androidroleplay.fk4.de.hs_bremen.de/GetSumOfTwoInts";
    String URL = "http://192.168.178.28:8080/WebProject_DB16/services/HelloWorldWS?wsdl";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("Operand1");
        pi.setValue(2);
        pi.setType(int.class);
        Request.addProperty(pi);

        PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
        pi2.setName("Operand2");
        pi2.setValue(5);
        pi2.setType(int.class);
        Request.addProperty(pi2);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

//        envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Integer",);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try
        {
             // Hier folgt die Authentifikation mit dem User Admin und Passwort Admin
            List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
            headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode("tomcat:tomcat".getBytes()))); // "username:password"

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerList);
            androidHttpTransport.debug=true;

            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
            String result =  response.getAttributeAsString(0);

            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView);
            tv.setText("Text: " + result); //"CategoryId: " +C.getCategoryId() + " Name: " + C.getName() + " Description: " + C.getDescription()
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this my Webservice:

```
public class HelloWorldWS
{   

    public int GetSumOfTwoInts(int Operand1, int Operand2 )
    {
        System.out.println(Operand1+ " + "+ Operand2 +" = "+ (Operand1 + Operand2));

       return Operand1 + Operand2;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service method returns only a integer value. In ksoap2, if webservice response has only one value(integer, string..) you should use

```
SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```

and `response.toString();` is result that you want.
If your response has complex types (Objects), you should use

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SoapObject resultObj = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
String result = (String)resultObj.getProperty(0);
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't works but this solution i need. THis is the Exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive`. What could i do?

Comment: then use
`SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
String str=response.toString();`

Comment: `KvmSerializable ks = (KvmSerializable)envelope.bodyIn;
String[] temp=new String[ks.getPropertyCount()];
                for(int i=0;i<ks.getPropertyCount();i++)
                {
                  temp[i]= ks.getProperty(i).toString(); 
                }`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
return result;
```