# Getting ksoap object from HttpTransportSE.responseDump

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am clueless how to proceed further while converting `transport.responseDump` which returns string(xml data in string form) to ksoap object. 
May be some code snippet will help me in describing my problem:

```
synchronized (transportLockObject)
        {
            transport.debug = true;            
            String soapAction = TARGET_NAMESPACE+"/"+method;

            try {
                transport.call(soapAction, envelope);
            } catch (SSLHandshakeException she) {
                she.printStackTrace();          
            }
        }
         System.out.println("Response ----------"+transport.responseDump);
```

This is how I am getting the responseDump. I am saving this dump so that it can be used later (say when I don't want actual online data for testing purpose or no connection[*whatever*]). 
Later what normally I do is

```
        Object response = envelope.getResponse();

        //Check if response is available... if yes parse the response
        if (response != null)
        {
            if (myResponse != null)
            {
                myResponse.parse(response);
            }
        }
```

This response which I passed in parse() is actually a soap object. **Can Any body tell how can I convert my value returned from transport.responseDump into soap object, so that I can pass it into parse() method?**

Any clue or link will be helpful. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "bodyIn" instead of 'getResponse'

after

```
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
```

Use

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
UserDefined resultVariable = new UserDefined(j);
```

The UserDefined constructor should be able to handle this.

If your expected object is a user defined object you should implement that with kvmserializable. you can find some example here.

[KSoap2 and KvmSerializable - How to Send complex Objects like Stringarrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999763/ksoap2-and-kvmserializable-how-to-send-complex-objects-like-stringarrays)