# KSoap2 and KvmSerializable-Send class object with a list field to webservice in java android

Tags: java, android, web-services, ksoap2

I develop an android application and i try to call a web service and pass a class object as parameter to a method.That class has a list field called Partner and i think that this field has never sent to the web service.

this is my Customer class:

```
package com.testcustomer22;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class Customer extends MainActivity implements KvmSerializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public String Code;
public String Name;
public String VATNo;
public String PriceList;
public List<Partner> Partner = new ArrayList<Partner>();


    public Customer(){}


    public Customer(String cCode, String cName, String cVATNo, String cPriceList,    List<Partner> cPartner) {

    Code = cCode;
    Name = cName;
    VATNo = cVATNo;
    PriceList = cPriceList;
    Partner = cPartner;
}

public Object getProperty(int index) {
    Object res = null;
    switch(index)
    {
      case 0:
        res = this.Code;
        break;
  case 1:
        res = this.Name;
        break;
  case 2:
    res = this.VATNo;
        break;
  case 3:
        res = this.PriceList;
    break;
      case 4:
    res = this.Partner;
    break;
    }
    return res;
}

public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 4;
}

public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch (index)
    {
    case 0:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "Code";
        break;
    case 1:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "Name";
        break;
    case 2:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "VATNo";
        break;
    case 3:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "PriceList";
        break; 
    case 4:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.VECTOR_CLASS;
        info.name = "Partner";
        break; 
  }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0:
        this.Code = value.toString();
        break;
    case 1:
        this.Name = value.toString();
        break;
case 2:
        this.VATNo = value.toString();
        break;
    case 3:
    this.PriceList = value.toString();
        break;
case 4:
        this.Partner = (List<com.testcustomer22.Partner>) value;
        break;
default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my MainActivity where i call the webservice:

```
package com.testcustomer22;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{    

    private static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/Service/GetCustomer";
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME1 = "GetCustomer";
    private static String URL = "http://xxxxxxxx:8000/Service?wsdl";


    TextView TextView01;
    EditText editText2,editText1;
    Button button1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
            @Override 
               public void onClick(View v)
               { 

            TextView01 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                Customer C = new Customer();
                C.setProperty(0,"0000000000000000");

                    //Initialize soap request + add parameters
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);

                    //Declare the version of the SOAP request
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);

                //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
                PropertyInfo pi =new PropertyInfo(); 
                pi.setName("customer");    //Define the variable name
                pi.setValue(C);            //set value for userName variable
                pi.setType(C.getClass());  //Define the type of the variable
                request.addProperty(pi);   //Pass properties to the variable 


                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                envelope.dotNet = true;     


                envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "customer", new Customer().getClass());


            try{

                    editText2.setText("before call websrv");

                        //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);

                        //Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                    Log.i("REQUEST--->", androidHttpTransport.requestDump); 
                    Log.i("RESPONSE--->", androidHttpTransport.responseDump); 

                    Log.i("Response.toString()---------->", response.toString()); 

                }catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
        });
     }
 }
```

I add the line "Log.i("REQUEST--->"..." as to print me the request that sends to the service.The problem is that when i write "return 5" to the "getPropertyCount()" method of my Customer class and try to run my main activity it throws me to the exception.And when i write "return4" to the "getPropertyCount()" it returns me this:

```
I/REQUEST---------------------->(1156): <v:Envelope 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header /><v:Body><GetCustomer 
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" id="o0" c:root="1"><customer i:type="d:anyType"><Code 
i:type="d:string">0000000000000000</Code><Name i:null="true" /><VATNo i:null="true" />
<PriceList i:null="true" /></customer></GetCustomer></v:Body></v:Envelope>
```

It shows all the other fields except from the Partner.

If you have any ideas how to pass the list field right please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: does your Customer class on the webserver have the same attributes, as the class in your android app? Could you pls post your wsdl-file? I would have post this answer as comment, but i don't have the rights to do that :/

Comment: Sorry but i can't post the wsdl and my web server has an operation which takes class objects as parameters.This is a part of wsdl with this operation : 

<wsdl:message name="Service_GetCustomer_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCustomer"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="Service_GetCustomer_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetCustomerResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>


Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The first thing i guess is that you are never setting a partner to your customer. The second thing is that i guess that the getPropertyInfo will call the getPropertyCount method and this may raises the error you were talking about. May you could post the error message?

Comment: I dont think i got any errors.The problem is, as i understand from the returnings of the line:"Log.i("REQUEST--->"...", that does not send the "Partner" list with the request to the server and also the command "Log.i("Response.toString()---------->", response.toString());" returns anyType{}.And i dont know if i didnt send the object in the right way or i dont serialize it right or something else.

Comment: Ah ok, i thought because you have written "The problem is that when i write "return 5" to the "getPropertyCount()" method of my Customer class and try to run my main activity it throws me to the exception". I think it is all sent the right way, the Partner-list isnt send because your customer you're trying to send doesnt own a partner-list so it's null.

Comment: but i create a Partner list in the customer class??What else must i do?

Comment: Your Customer contains a ArrayList<Partner> thats true, but as you initalize your Customer in your mainActivity you aren't setting it. So this list equals null. You have to set this List in your MainActivty like `List<Partner> partnerList = new ArrayList<Partner>(); partnerList.add(new Partner(...)); c.setProperty(4, partnerList)` then your customer should contain a partner in his list. Hope that helps

Comment: thanks for your help but it doesnt return the Partner in the rwquest.If you want upvote my question please.I appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you please post your edited code or edit it in your question? You could also have a look on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999763/ksoap2-and-kvmserializable-how-to-send-complex-objects-like-stringarrays), seems to be a similar problem

Comment: here is the edited part as you told me to do:

Customer C = new Customer();
C.setProperty(0,"0000000000000000");
           
List<Partner> partnerList = new ArrayList<Partner>(); 
partnerList.add(new Partner("dkidfsjdds","dfas","dsaf","asdf")); 
              
C.setProperty(4, partnerList);
//Initialize soap request + add parameters
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);

Thanks for the question but i have read it already.

Comment: What does the LogCat acctually say when you are running your app?

Comment: there is no errors or warnings.The LogCat onlys gives me the prints i have add to the code such as the request (posted in the question) the response and the response .toString which returns me anyType{}.

Comment: I'm sorry i acctually could not find the error.

Comment: Thanks for your try.If you like my question please upvote it as to see anyone who knows the answer.